# Why is my plotly graph overlapping over multiple categories?

Tags: python, plotly

When I am making a graph on plotly, my first graph (All) is working great. It has the 5 categories and, when you hover, adds up to 100%. [first graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m2Jd.png). When I move onto the second graph, this is where I start running into issues. When you click the 20 buttons, it comes up with this [The second graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRtcO.png). Now it has the 5 corresponding categories to the age group of 20 but it also includes the some categories for the 30s age group. How can I set it up so that it only shows the 5 categories for each corresponding age group?

Entire Code:

```html
p_info = pd.read_csv('PatientInfo.csv',parse_dates=['symptom_onset_date', 'confirmed_date', 'released_date', 'deceased_date'])

p_info = p_info.dropna(subset=['age'])
p_info = p_info.dropna(subset=['infection_case'])

#Lets Group these together to make analysis easier 
def group(x):
    if "Shincheonji Church" in x:
        x="Church"
        return x
    if "Onchun Church" in x:
        x="Church"
        return x
    if "Dongan Church" in x:
        x="Church"
        return x
    if "Geochang Church" in x:
        x="Church"
        return x    
    if "SMR Newly Planted Churches Group" in x:
        x="Church"
        return x
    if "Pilgrimage to Israel" in x:
        x="Church"
        return x
    if "River of Grace Community Church" in x:
        x="Church"
        return x
    if "Biblical Language study meeting" in x:
        x="Church"
        return x
    if "etc" in x:
        x="etc"
        return x
    if "contact with patient" in x:
        x="Direct Contact with Patient"
        return x
    if "overseas inflow" in x:
        x="Overseas"
        return x   
    else:
        x="Group"
        return x 
        
p_info['infection_type'] = p_info['infection_case'].apply(group)
  
p_info['week'] = p_info['confirmed_date'].dt.weekofyear

type_by_time = p_info.groupby(['week', 'infection_type']).size().unstack().fillna(0)
# type_by_time = type_by_time.div(type_by_time.sum(axis=1), axis=0) * 100
type_by_time
type_by_time_age = []
# df = PatientRoute.merge(PatientInfo, on='patient_id')
df = p_info
for age_group in ['20','30','40','50','60','70','80']:
    new_type_by_time = df.groupby(['week', 'infection_type']).size().unstack().fillna(0)        
    type_by_time_age.append(new_type_by_time)
    
colors = px.colors.qualitative.Light24
x = type_by_time.index.tolist()
categories = ['Church', 'Direct Contact with Patient', 'Group', 'Overseas', 'etc']
fig = go.Figure()
    
for i, cat in enumerate(categories):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=type_by_time[cat],
                        hoverinfo='x+y',
                        mode='lines',
                        line=dict(width=0.5, color=colors[i]),
                        name=cat,
                        stackgroup='one',
                        groupnorm='percent'
                            ))
    
for age, df in enumerate(type_by_time_age):
    for i, cat in enumerate(categories):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index.tolist(), y=df[cat],
                            hoverinfo='y',
                            mode='lines',
                            line=dict(width=0.5, color=colors[i]),
                            name=cat,
                            stackgroup=age,
                            groupnorm='percent',
                            visible=False)) 

fig.update_layout(
    title='Where do most people get infected?',
    showlegend=True,
    xaxis=dict(
        range=[4, 19],
        ticksuffix=' week'
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        type='linear',
        range=[1, 100],
        ticksuffix='%'))

menus = []
for i, name in enumerate(['All','20','30','40','50','60','70','80']):
    d = dict(label=name,
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False]*i*9 + [True]*9 + [False]*(8-i-1)*9},
                           {"title": f"Where do most people get infected? (Age: {name})"}])
    menus.append(d)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="buttons",
            direction="right",
            active=0,
            x=1,
            y=1.2,
            buttons=menus,
        )
    ],
    xaxis_title="weeks",
    yaxis_title="% in group of people who get infected",
)

fig.show()
```

Here is the link to the kaggle dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/kimjihoo/coronavirusdataset

Comment: When I tried to run the code, I found that 1) the data was not extracted by age, `for age_group in ['20s','30s','40s','50s','60s','70s','80s']:df=p_info; df=df[df['age']==age_group]` and 2) the number of Boolean values in the button display control did not match the number of graphs. `args=[{"visible": [False]*i*9 + [True]*9 + [False]*(8-i-1)*9},...`